# Why is my microphone's volume level keep resetting?

Tags: windows, audio, microphone

For some reason the microphone volume level keeps setting itself back to 0 and i have no idea why. This has nothing to do with Skype or MSN Messenger and setting the communication tab to "Do Nothing" under Recording devices>turtlebeach px3> properties does nothing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/95aeM.jpg here's what it looks like.

That is what it looks like. I would then change the slider to 100 and then unmute the mic, but after a few seconds it would go back to zero.
My Headset is a Turtle Beach PX3. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've been trying all day to figure out this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Try going into **Recording devices** and make sure that the microphone is set as the **Default Device** and as the **Default Communications Device**. You may also want to disable any other recording devices that are connected.

If that doesn't do it, right click on the device's icon and go into its **Properties**. On the **Listen** tab, make sure the "Listen to this device" box is unchecked. On the **Advanced** tab, there is a checkbox for "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device." Uncheck that box and click **Apply**.

[image]

## **Update:**

It looks like they have updated the transmitter's firmware. 

[Download the file here.](http://support.turtlebeach.com/files/444/)

[Firmware upgrade guide here.](http://support.turtlebeach.com/entry/830517548/)

Comment: I've done that, and nothing seemed to help. Any more suggestions? the microphone works on other computers, and i had uninstalled and re-installed the drivers.

Comment: The headset has an integrated DAC and connects via USB, right? Are using Windows default drivers or the manufacturer's drivers?

Comment: When I reinstalled the drivers, it said "Searching Windows Update for drivers" or something. I think that would be windows. And yes its wireless and the reciever box is connected to the computer via USB.

Comment: Were you able to find the manufacturer's drivers? If so, remove the device and turn off the auto driver install feature in "Devices and Printers." Next, uninstall and delete the Windows drivers. Once that's done, install the manufacturer's drivers.

Comment: I poked around on the Turtle Beach website and it looks like they don't have a proprietary driver this device. There is, however, a firmware upgrade. I'm not sure if it will address your particular problem but its worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

For almost a year I have been plagued by the same problem of my microphone level being randomly reset to zero. Literally dozens of people have reported this problem on the Internet, with no real solution, at least not an easy solution. TODAY I FOUND AN EASY SOLUTION THAT REALLY WORKS! Here it is.

These instructions are for the Windows 7 Operating System.
Click Start, Control Panel, Sound, Recording. 
Then, in the list of devices, highlight the name of the microphone you are using. Mine is the Realtek High Definition Audio default device.This also works for a USB microphone.
Click Properties, Levels.
Set the Microphone level to zero and the Microphone Boost to +30 DB.
Click OK, OK.
That solved the problem for me, completely and permanently!